# Narrowing-down the return type of an implemented method

Tags: php, oop, php-7, return-type

I'm trying to specify two interfaces for class A that returns instances of class B, and for class B itself.

I'm declaring return types on the interface.

Say I've got two interfaces.

Some kind of RepositoryInterface, that has a `get()` method that returns an object implementing the ElementInterface

```php
<?php

namespace App\Contracts;

interface RepositoryInterface {

    public function get( $key ) : ElementInterface;

}
```

And an element interface:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Contracts;

interface ElementInterface { }
```

Now, my implementation of the repository declares a return-type that is a specific class `MyElement`.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

class MyRepository implements RepositoryInterface {

    public function get( $key ) : MyElement {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Where `MyElement` is some class implementing `ElementInterface`.

... this results in a fatal error:

```
Declaration of MyRepository::get( $key ): MyElement must be compatible with RepositoryInterface::get( $key ): ElementInterface
```

If I would not specify the return types on the interface, this would work perfectly fine. Yet, I want to constrain the type of class returned by any class implementing the `RepositoryInterface`.

1. Is it true that this is not possible in PHP 7.1?
2. If this is indeed not possible, is that because my pattern is incorrect?
3. How could I declare the return type of my interface methods without specifying an actual implementation of this type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with any version of PHP lower than 7.4.

If your interface contains:

```
public function get( $key ) : ElementInterface;
```

Then your class needs to be:

```
class MyRepository implements RepositoryInterface {

    public function get( $key ) : ElementInterface {

        returns new MyElement();
        // which in turn implements ElementInterface
    }
}
```

The declaration of a class implementing an interface has to match **exactly** the contract laid out by the interface.

By declaring that it has to return a particular interface instead of an specific implementation, you are giving you leeway on how to implement it (now you could return `MyElement` or `AnotherElement` as long as both implemented `ElementInterface`); but the method declaration has to be the same anyway.

See it working [here](https://repl.it/repls/MulticoloredSimilarServers).

---

Starting with PHP 7.4, due to be released in November 2019, [covariance will be supported for return types](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/covariant-returns-and-contravariant-parameters). By then, this would work.

Comment: `MyRepository` and `MyElement` interact with each other. They provide additional methods, next to those defined in the interfaces.
Is there another way to indicate that the return type of for example `MyRepository::get()` is more specific than `ElementInterface`, e.g. `MyElement`?

Comment: No, the declaration needs to match the declaration of the interface. You can have some variance in the actual implementation (again, returning a object of a class that implements the interface that you declared as returning); but as you already discovered, a mismatch in declaration will get you a fatal error.