# Concretize return type of an abstract class method

Tags: php, oop, interface

How do I concretize return type of an abstract class method?

Why does this:

```php
interface I {}

class A implements I {}

abstract class CA {
    abstract public function foo() : I;
}

class C extends CA {
    public function foo() : A
    {
        return new A;
    }
}

(new C)->foo();
```

lead to `Fatal error: Declaration of C::foo(): A must be compatible with CA::foo(): I`?
Since return type `A` fullfills the requirement of implementing interface `I`.

Comment: In `C` if you change your definition to `public function foo() : I` it would work, after all - your abstract class says that it should handle anything of type `I` and so all subclasses should stick to that.

Comment: @yivi i think it's not dupicate since this question is about return types and not arguments.

Comment: @Inceddy, Actually, it's the same issue. Do not focus on "arguments" or "return types". It's about declaring a method and respecting the signature of the parent declaration. In both cases is the same thing, trying to use a more restrictive declaration.

Comment: As stated in the answer in the dupe, this is a feature that could be supported in 7.4, but since you are not using 7.4, this is the issue you encounter (and thus the dupe applies, which also gives you the explanation of why it works this way, and the link to the upcoming changes in 7.4).

Comment: This other Q&A is probably a better dupe target anyway, which deals return types: [Narrowing-down the return type of an implemented method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49352636/narrowing-down-the-return-type-of-an-implemented-method/). I've updated the answer to cover 7.4 changes.

Answer (score -1):

Your code will work fine if you return `I` instead of `A` because PHP does not allow [covariant return types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type). The underlying question is what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The idea was to have an abstract base class "AbstractServices" implementing several shared methods and then to have concrete "UserServcies" (only handles User objects), "ClientServices" (only handles Client entities). May be traits are the better choise.

Comment: "Cavariant return types" put me on track and as stated here https://wiki.php.net/rfc/covariant-returns-and-contravariant-parameters this feature is introduced in PHP 7.4.